# When should I use the Elixir Process registry vs named processes?

Tags: elixir

I've got thousands of processes in my application.

I've used a sensible naming schema to send messages between them, but I've noticed this thing exists:

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/Registry.html

What are the limitations of named processes, and in what circumstances should I decide whether to use Registry instead?

Answer (score 3):

The main limitation of named processes would be atoms are not garbage collected and the total limit of atoms is by default slightly more than one million (check with `:erlang.system_info(:atom_limit)`.)

It might be extended by passing `+t N` erlang option, but in general the rule of thumb would be “atoms should not be created dynamically.” (That’s why `String.to_existing_atom/1` function ever exists, and why all the *JSON* parsers produce keys as strings, not atoms, for instance.)

That said, the proper strategy would be to use `{:via, …}` names for dynamically created processes unless you are sure the total number would not be grown infinitely during the application lifecycle.